# foreign key references a composite primary key in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I made a create table migration like this:

```
Schema::create('judgments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('judgment_id')->unique();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('virtual_member_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('member_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('form_id');
        $table->integer('judgement')->range(0,101); // give a number between 0 to 101 to give a judge
        $table->timestamps();

    });
```

and then I made another migration (add_foreign_key_to_judgments) like this:

```
Schema::table('judgments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        
        $table->foreign('virtual_member_id')->references(['virtual_id','employee_id'])->on('virtual_members')->onDelete('cascade');

    });
```

I also tried to make (add_foreign_key_to_judgments) migration like this:

```
Schema::table('judgments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        
        $table->foreign('virtual_member_id')->references('virtual_member_id')->on('virtual_members')->onDelete('cascade');

    });
```

where virtual_members migration is :

```
Schema::create('virtual_members', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('virtual_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('employee_id');
        $table->foreign('virtual_id')->references('virtual_id')->on('virtuals')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('employee_id')->references('employee_id')->on('employees')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['virtual_id','employee_id'],'virtual_member_id')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I got this error when I run php artisan migrate:

```
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1239 Incorrect foreign key definition for 'judgments_virtual_member_id_foreign': Key reference and table reference don't match (SQL: alter table `judgments` add constraint `judgments_virtual_member_id_foreign` foreign key (`virtual_member_id`) references `virtual_members` (`virtual_id`, `employee_id`) on delete cascade)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this has recently changed or not, but last time I checked __Laravel did not support composite primary keys__.

Comment: @IGP  the Eloquent models don't support composite primary keys but migrations do